# Android Studio not showing build error in Xiaomi phone

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xiaomi

My application restarts when I have errors in my code, the problem is that I cannot know in which line of code the error is because Android Studio does not tell me. I have this problem on a Xiaomi mi 11i phone (Android 11, MIUI 12.5.3) I can only see blue text.

[image]

I have a Samsung J260 device in which I have no problems (when there are problems in my code it always tells me which line it is on), I don't like to do tests on my Samsung because it takes too long. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should switch off the `MIUI Optimization` option from `Developer Options`.

Also check if `USB debugging` is switched on.

Comment: USB debugging was already activated, but I had MIUI optimization active, deactivating it as you indicated solved my problem! Thanks